# scrollTo() for horizontalScrollView not working

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I inflate another layout to appear below some view in my current layout.

This is done like this:

```
       LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rootView = vi.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_scroll_view, null);

    horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hsv_suggestions_scroll_view);
    LinearLayout suggestionsContainer = (LinearLayout) horizontalScrollView.findViewById(R.id.ll_suggestions_container);
```

and I can confirm that it appears in the right place since I add some Views in it after a while and they all appear.

The layout I inflate is :

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/hsv_suggestions_scroll_view"
android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingTop="16dp" android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/ll_suggestions_container"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"    android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

just a `HorizontalScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` as a child.
The Views I add later are all of them `TextView`s.

Now after a user action (write some text on an editText) I'm trying to scroll to that View and highlight it. Highlight works. What does not work is scroll.

I have tried :

```
 horizontalScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

   horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollTo, 0);
   }
}, 300);
```

where variable `scrollTo` is what I get when I apply `getLeft()` to the View I wanna scroll to. I can confirm that it takes various values.

Anyone can help me with that ?

Comment: I just threw together this same situation, and it's working just fine for me. Have you tried putting a random number into your `smoothScrollTo()` to see of it will scroll for anything?

Comment: @idratherbeintheair yes I have tried adding some random numbers but didn't help

Comment: So it didn't scroll when you used random numbers either?

Comment: nope. That's why I wrote "not working" in the title. Maybe something with parent's View width or height ?

Comment: So basically the user types something, then you add that text to a TextView then add that to the container inside the ScrollView, then you want to scroll to that view, right?

If that's the case, it's possible you're not waiting long enough after adding it to scroll to it. Try increasing your 300 millisecond wait on the `postDelayed`?

Comment: Nope I inject the `horizontalScrollView` below the editText where user types something. Then when user types something (bigger than 2 letters - but just for testing I just type 3 letters and stop there) I'm trying to scroll to a textView inside the `horizontalScrollView` which is similar to what user typed. I have also tried increating the delay to 2000ms but didn't scroll either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128868/discussion-between-idratherbeintheair-and-mes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to using a RecyclerView with a LinearLayoutManager with orientation set to Horizontal. Like this:

**scroll_view.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollContainer"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**Note: the layoutManager tag is required here for the layout to inflate. After it's inflated, we're going to set it programatically as well because otherwise we'll get an exception because the RecyclerView basically disposes of it before it's done with it.**

**OptionAdapter.java**

```
public class OptionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OptionAdapter.OptionHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private ArrayList<String> options;

    public OptionAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        options = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public OptionHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new OptionHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(OptionHolder holder, int position) {
        String option = options.get(position);

        ((TextView) holder.itemView).setText(option);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return options != null ? options.size() : 0;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void addOption(String option, Integer index) {
        if (index != null && index <= options.size()) {
            options.add(index, option);
        } else {
            options.add(option);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class OptionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public OptionHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

**text_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Setting everything up**

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final RecyclerView scrollView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.scroll_view, container, false);
scrollView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

final OptionAdapter adapter = new OptionAdapter(this);
scrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`container` here is whatever view is going to be holding the `RecyclerView`. In my code, I've got it in a `LinearLayout`.

**Adding a view to the list**

`adapter.addOption("The Added One", null);`

**Or if you want to add it to a specific position in the list.**

`adapter.addOption("The Added One", position);`

**Scrolling to a specific position**

`scrollView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);`

**Scrolling to a specific item in the list**

`scrollView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getOptions().indexOf("ItemText"));`

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Works as expected! Thanks a lot ! Think it was some problem with the inflation of the `horizontalScrollView` but `RecyclerView` is great for those cases too.

Answer (score 4):

Got a similar issue.

I guess the root cause is that the UI was not yet rendered at that moment, causing the scroll not to work properly.

I just had to wrap my call to `smoothScrollTo` into `.post` as follows:

```
mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(xxx, yyy);
    }
});
```

Notice that I do a post directly on the scrollView to make sure it is executed after it is being rendered. For example, doing a `getActivity().runOnUIThread()` would not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of smoothScrollTo(), try using scrollTo().

 Make sure that your getLeft() is really returning a value > 0;

Comment: `smoothScrollTo()` is working for me, and it gives a smoother UX.

Comment: I have tried both `smoothScrollTo()` and `scrollTo()`. I can confirm that getLeft() gives me values > 0

Comment: use debugger and check that it is entering the runnable. Also see your logcat when debugger pass over the smoothScrollTo() function.